# Object Oriented Design Patterns for Model Attribute Events

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I'm trying to figure out the best way to encapsulate the following scenario with Object Oriented Design principles. What type of design pattern would best suit?

I've added very basic class definitions below, basically a person has a plan and a credit card. When a person changes their plan, we want to bill them the difference (if the plan's cost was more) and create an Event

I *could* do this in callbacks or an observer, check if the `Plan` for that `Person` changed, but in a larger system with lots of cross model behaviour, this becomes unmanageable and difficult to test with lots of unrelated callbacks affecting state.

```
class Person
   has_one :plan
   has_one :credit_card
   has_many :events
end

class Plan
   attr_accessible :cost
end

class CreditCard
  def charge_card(amount)
    ...
  end
end

class Event
  attr_accessible :message
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, your credit card is your condition based on which your billing differs. [Strategy](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) pattern is probably the right one to fit in, IMHO.

[Replacing Conditional with Strategy](http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/conditionalWithStrategy.html)

Comment: Thanks Arun! I thought about a strategy, but I'm less concerned with *if* we bill than the act of how to pass the messages around. When Person changes, both CreditCard and Event need to be notified, but neither notifications really apply to Person's domain.

Comment: @GregJ Good point. So, there are two problems in hand. You could always use Strategy for your calculation purposes and like you mentioned in your question, use Observer for publish/subscribe problem.

Comment: Thanks Arun, I figured Observer would probably be the way to go.

Comment: @GregJ or you could use both. No harm in using patterns hand in hand. After all, you do have two problems.

Comment: Definitely! Sorry I should have said, "I figure the Observer would probably be the way to go... for the message passing issue" :)